# How to create a loop inside terraform resource?

Tags: terraform

Relatively simple question.

I don't know if this is something terraform can do already but I would like to create objects in a terraform resource using a for loop. Below you can see an example of what I mean. I already loop over the resource to make the pipelines but I would also like to loop over the deployment object so one codeCommit repository can be pushed to multiple ECS services without having to create a new pipeline. Is this possible?

The section I would like to loop over has:

> PLACE MULTIPLE DEPLOYMENTS USING SOME FOR LOOP

```
resource "aws_codepipeline" "pipeline" {
  count    = "${local.numRepo}"
  name     = "${element(var.respository_names, count.index)}-${terraform.workspace}"
  role_arn = "${var.role}"

  artifact_store {
    location = "${element(aws_s3_bucket.artifact.*.bucket, count.index)}"
    type     = "S3"
  }

  stage {
    name = "Source"

    action {
      name             = "Source"
      category         = "Source"
      owner            = "AWS"
      provider         = "CodeCommit"
      version          = "1"
      output_artifacts = ["source"]

      configuration {
        RepositoryName = "${element(var.respository_names, count.index)}"
        BranchName     = "${element(split(",",lookup(var.codepipelines_info,"${terraform.workspace}.${element(var.respository_names,count.index)}")),1)}"
      }
    }
  }

  stage {
    name = "Test"

    action {
      name             = "Test"
      category         = "Test"
      owner            = "AWS"
      provider         = "CodeBuild"
      input_artifacts  = ["source"]
      output_artifacts = ["tested"]
      version          = "1"

      configuration {
        ProjectName = "${element(aws_codebuild_project.openjobs_build_test.*.name, count.index)}"
      }
    }
  }

  stage {
    name = "Build"

    action {
      name             = "Build"
      category         = "Build"
      owner            = "AWS"
      provider         = "CodeBuild"
      version          = "1"
      input_artifacts  = ["source"]
      output_artifacts = ["imagedefinitions"]

      configuration {
        ProjectName = "${element(aws_codebuild_project.openjobs_build.*.name, count.index)}"
      }
    }
  }

  stage { 
    name = "Production"

    action { <<<PLACE MULTIPLE DEPLOYMENTS USING SOME FOR LOOP
      name            = "Deploy"
      category        = "Deploy"
      owner           = "AWS"
      provider        = "ECS"
      input_artifacts = ["imagedefinitions"]
      version         = "1"

      configuration {
        ClusterName = "${var.ecs_cluster_name}"
        ServiceName = "${terraform.workspace}-${element(var.respository_names, count.index)}"
        FileName    = "imagedefinitions.json"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is coming in Terraform 0.12 with [dynamic blocks](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/hashicorp-terraform-0-12-preview-for-and-for-each). Until then some resources are hackable but not easily so I'd probably wait for the upcoming release.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for.

Comment: This would be tricky to do for all stages because only test and build have similar `configuration` blocks whereas `Production` and `Source` are more unique.